# Custom PFTableViewCell getting 'squished' - Constraint error in Swift + Parse

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I have set up a Parse `PFTableViewController` and want to fill the table with some custom cells.

When the view loads, the `PFTableView` is successfully populated with cells of my custom cell type which have a cell height GREATER than the default 44 (I made a Class for the custom cell which is a Subclass of `PFTableViewCell` etc.) and when I tap on one, it fires a Segue to a detail view that I have made.

BUT! When I tap "< Back" to go back to the `PFTableViewController` with all my custom cells, the cell height changes back to 44 and everything gets squished!

(I would post a screenshot, but I do not yet have enough reputation)

I also get the following error when I first load up the `PFTableViewController`:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc859f82d90 H:[UILabel:0x7fc859f8b930'00%'(48)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc859fa95c0 H:[UILabel:0x7fc859fa9350(12)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc859faa1e0 H:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7fc859fa9350]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc859f88bc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc859faa280 H:[UILabel:0x7fc859fa9350]-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x7fc859f8bfd0'Course Name']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc859faa390 UILabel:0x7fc859fa97f0'Course Code'.leading == UILabel:0x7fc859f8bfd0'Course Name'.leading>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc859faa3e0 UILabel:0x7fc859f8b930'00%'.trailing == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc859f88bc0.trailingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc859faa430 H:[UILabel:0x7fc859fa97f0'Course Code']-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x7fc859f8b930'00%']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc859fb25c0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc859f88bc0(34)]>"
)
```

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc859f82d90 H:[UILabel:0x7fc859f8b930'00%'(48)]>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem or what might be causing it?

**NOTE: I am still very new to StackOverflow so please tell me if I have not been clear enough :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well asked question in my opinion!
Are you using?:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
     return yourSpecifiedHeight
}
```

If not, make sure that's specified so that when the table reloads, its uses that value.

Comment: No problem! Just remember, when working with tableViews, even in storyboards or Xibs, you'll need to specify everything you want custom in the delegate and datasource :)